# module Language.Haskell.Generate.Expression fail

Tags: haskell

https://github.com/bennofs/haskell-generate

```
module Language.Haskell.Generate.Expression 
  ( Expression(..)
  , app
  ) where

import Language.Haskell.Exts.Syntax

newtype Expression t = Expression { runExpression :: Exp }

app :: Expression (a -> b) -> Expression a -> Expression b
app (Expression a) (Expression b) = Expression $ App a b


/workspace/haskell/haskell-generate/src/Language/Haskell/Generate/Expression.hs:8:54:
Expecting one more argument to ‘Exp’
Expected a type, but ‘Exp’ has kind ‘* -> *’
In the type ‘Exp’
In the definition of data constructor ‘Expression’
In the newtype declaration for ‘Expression’
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

any ideas?

Comment: `Exp` is type constructor that need a type as parameter. Can it be `t` ?

Comment: The type parameter to `Exp` does not represent the type which is represented by the term (i.e. `x :: Exp t` does not represent `x :: t`) - the type parameter is an annotation. You probably want `Exp ()` or possible you want to keep the annotation - `newtype Expression ann t = Expression (Exp ann)`